A Diophantine Problem on Divisibility Involving Numbers of the Form $p = 4m + 1$
Conjecture. For any $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ such that $4m+1$  is a prime number, there exists a pair $ (n,j)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\times\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, such that
$$(4j+3)⋅n−1∣(4j+3)⋅m+(j+1)$$
Context and Motivation. This problem arises from a general investigation into Diophantine equations and divisibility properties related to primes of the form $4m + 1$. These primes, known as Pythagorean primes, play a central role in number theory, especially in relation to quadratic forms and integer factorization.
Question. Is the above conjecture true, and if yes, is there a constructive way to find $n$ and $j$ in terms of $m$?
Further Considerations. I am particularly interested in understanding the divisibility properties of expressions involving Pythagorean primes and how these might be generalized. Any insights into the modular arithmetic involved or relevant number-theoretic results would be greatly appreciated.
References and Related Work. This question builds on previous results in number theory related to Pythagorean primes, modular forms, and Diophantine equations. In particular, references to modular inverses, quadratic reciprocity, and the study of divisibility in the context of prime numbers of the form $p = 4m + 1$ would be most useful.
Additional Information. I have written a program to verify the divisibility condition for $ m < 100000 $ and found that whenever $p=4m+1$ is a prime, there always exists a corresponding $ (n,j) $ that satisfies the condition. Here are some examples（one solution only）:

For $ m = 1 $, $ p = 5 $, $ n = 1 $, $ j = 0 $
For $ m = 3 $, $ p = 13 $, $ n = 1 $, $ j = 0 $
For $ m = 4 $, $ p = 17 $, $ n = 1 $, $ j = 1 $
For $ m = 18 $, $ p = 73 $, $ n = 2 $, $ j = 0 $
For $ m = 60 $, $ p = 241 $, $ n = 1 $, $ j = 5 $
For $ m = 102 $, $ p = 409 $, $ n = 4 $, $ j = 3 $
For $ m = 300 $, $ p = 1201 $, $ n = 6 $, $ j = 0 $
For $ m = 312 $, $ p = 1249 $, $ n = 5 $, $ j = 5 $
For $ m = 630 $, $ p = 2521 $, $ n = 2 $, $ j = 3 $

When I removed the restriction that $ p = 4m + 1 $ must be prime, I noticed a pattern in the values of $ m $ that do not satisfy the divisibility condition. The following are some values of $ m $ for which the condition does not hold:

For $ m = 2 $, $ p = 9 $
For $ m = 6 $, $ p = 25 $
For $ m = 12 $, $ p = 49 $
For $ m = 20 $, $ p = 81 $
For $ m = 26 $, $ p = 105 $
For $ m = 30 $, $ p = 121 $
For $ m = 42 $, $ p = 169 $
For $ m = 56 $, $ p = 225 $
For $ m = 72 $, $ p = 289 $
For $ m = 90 $, $ p = 361 $
For $ m = 110 $, $ p = 441 $
For $ m = 116 $, $ p = 465 $
For $ m = 132 $, $ p = 529 $
For $ m = 146 $, $ p = 585 $
For $ m = 156 $, $ p = 625 $
For $ m = 182 $, $ p = 729 $
For $ m = 200 $, $ p = 801 $
For $ m = 210 $, $ p = 841 $
For $ m = 240 $, $ p = 961 $
For $ m = 272 $, $ p = 1089 $
For $ m = 306 $, $ p = 1225 $

It appears that most of the values of $ m $ where the divisibility condition does not hold have the property that $ 4m + 1 $ is a perfect square of an odd number. However, there are some exceptions, such as $ m = 26 $ and $ m = 116 $.

The sets
$$G = {(n, j) \mid (4j + 3) \cdot n - 1 \mid (4j + 3) \cdot m + (j + 1), \ 4m + 1 \text{ is prime}}$$
and
$$H = {(n, j) \mid (4j + 3) \cdot n - 1 \mid (4j + 3) \cdot m + (j + 1)}$$
have been numerically verified, and it appears that $$G$$ is a strict subset of $$H$$.
This suggests that the condition $$4m + 1$$ being a prime number is too restrictive for this problem.

thanks GH for your efforts on editing the statement.
